# Express-session on two servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, express-session

I've been trying to use express-session on **two** local servers.

The **first server** is for manipulating the database and the **second** is for loading pages.
I want to save some data in the session from the first server and use it in the second server.

Here's the code of the first API

```
require("dotenv").config();

const express = require('express');
const mysql = require("mysql");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const cors = require("cors");

const apiApp = express();

apiApp.use(express.json());
apiApp.use(cors());

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  host: "localhost"
});

var algorithm = 'aes256'; // algorithm
var key = 'password';

apiApp.post('/api/Connexion', (req, res) => {

  let cipheriv = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, key);  
  let encryptedPassword = cipheriv.update(req.body.motDePasse, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipheriv.final('hex');

  var data = [req.body.courriel, encryptedPassword];

  const query = "SELECT * FROM utilisateurs WHERE courriel=? AND motDePasse=?";
  pool.query(query, data, (error, results) => {
    if (results[0] && !error) {
      res.send(true);
      req.session.courriel = req.body.courriel;
    } else {
      res.send(false);
    }
  });
});

module.exports = apiApp;
```

And the second

```
require("dotenv").config();

const express = require('express');
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");

const coreApp = express();

coreApp.use(express.json());
coreApp.use(cors());

let dir = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..') + '/'
coreApp.use(express.static(dir));

coreApp.get('/connexion', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session != undefined) {
        console.log(req.session.courriel);
    }
    res.sendFile(dir + "index.html");
});

coreApp.get('/application', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(dir + "application.html");
});

coreApp.get('/:a', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect("/");
});

module.exports = coreApp;
```

So, I am trying to set the session variable at **line 64** of the first code and use it at **line 17** of the second code.

How can I do it ?
Thanks !

Comment: Two servers don't share session data. The simple answer is to use a single server.

Comment: You can share session data between servers if you use a shared database as the session store, often redis, but any database can work as long as both servers access the same database for express-session storage.  There are express-session [storage providers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores) for dozens of databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share session data between servers if you use a shared database as the session store for express-session, often redis, but any database can work as long as both servers access the same database for express-session storage and express-session is configured properly.

There are [express-session storage providers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores) for dozens of databases, including [express-mysql-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mysql-session) that works with the database that you're already using.